# Add object to an array in a JSON `file` in Node.js for each request

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have an image on the frontend. When the user right clicks on the image, the coordinates of that point are stored in a variable and that variable is then sent to the node server using AJAX post request. Then in the server side I am storing the x,y coordinates into a file as objects. I want to keep on piling up the set of x,y coordinates into that same file as different objects from the previous, when the user right clicks at other places on the image. The problem is that when I right click on some other position, the coordinates of that point are replacing the previous ones in the file, instead of adding to the file and keeping the previous ones as well. How can I achieve that?

```
.post(function(request, response){
    console.log("Request received");
    var util = require('util');
    var coordinates = request.body;
    var imageCoordinates = JSON.stringify(coordinates);
    fs.writeFile('coords.json', imageCoordinates, finished);

    function finished(err){
        console.log('all set.');
    }

    console.log('coords are:', coordinates);        
    response.send("All OK");
});
```

This is the request handler function in my server.js file.

Comment: use  `fs.appendFile` instead..

Comment: so you have to save array of cordinates inside coords,json file right ?

Comment: @amyogiji yes exactly.

Comment: How big this array can grow? Is this to be gone to production? If yes will you be using mutiple instances (horizontal scaling like aws asg?). Implementation differs on these scenarios. For learning, it's as simple as read existing file into a var -> json parse it -> add new cordinates -> json stringify -> replace previous file using fs.writeFile

Comment: Another approach is to omit the closing `]}` of the array and using fs.write insert individual co-oridantes. for the final coordinate append the last `]}`

Comment: Or you can save the coordinates as csv and parse it back to JSON when you need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**fs.writeFile:** Asynchronously writes data to a file, replacing the file if it already exists.

**fs.appendFile:** Asynchronously append data to a file, creating the file if it does not yet exist.

Comment: Great! I am getting the objects now. But how can I store these in an array?

Comment: You can't store array in a file, since it is a file. But what you can do is store the objects with a separator in between and when reading the file, for using, you can read the contents of the file and split it to make it an array.

Comment: If you want to store the coordinated in an array, I'll suggest using a DB like mongoDB to do so, since MongoDB allows you to store JSON like docuements easily.

Comment: `Great! I am getting the objects now. But how can I store these in an array?`  Sometimes JSON is not the best option, if you were to use JSON here, you would need to read old, append new array item, write new.  But if you just did them as say CSV format, you can just keep appending to the end of the file..  No need for  (read/decode/add/encode/write)..

Answer (score 0):

Code has two issues,

use appendFile instead of writeFile, modified the code below.
Also you need to send the response once the write is completed.

> function finished(err){
>           console.log('all set.');
>           response.send("All OK");
>       }

Otherwise response might go earlier before the write is completed.

```
.post(function(request, response){
    console.log("Request received");
    var util = require('util');
    var coordinates = request.body;
    var imageCoordinates = JSON.stringify(coordinates);
    fs.appendFile('coords.json', imageCoordinates, finished);

    function finished(err){
        console.log('all set.');
        response.send("All OK");
    }

    console.log('coords are:', coordinates);        

});
```

Comment: Great! I am getting the objects now. But how can I store these in an array?