# How to seperate objects with commas when writing them to a json file using nodejs?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am sending right click coordinates from the client side to the server side and from there I am writing them down in a json file, having coordinates of different points stored as different objects. This is how my json file looks:

```
{"x":344,"y":158}{"x":367,"y":152}{"x":641,"y":129}
```

Now the problem is that I have to put a comma between the first two objects in order to make it a valid json. How can i do that? Here is my request handler function:

```
.post(function(request, response){
    console.log("Request received");
    var util = require('util');
    var coordinates = request.body;
    var imageCoordinates = JSON.stringify(coordinates, null, 2);
    fs.appendFile('coords.json', imageCoordinates, finished);

    function finished(err){
        console.log('all set.');
        response.send("All OK");
    }

    console.log('coords are:', coordinates);        

});
```

Comment: Just putting in some commas wouldn't make it valid JSON. Are you trying to create an array, like `[{"x":344,"y":158},{"x":367,"y":152},{"x":641,"y":129}]`, which would be valid JSON?

Comment: I'd recommend: read the file, turn that string into an object, add the new coordinate to the object, overwrite the file with that object (re-stringified, of course)

Comment: If you read my comment from your other post about JSON not been the best approach to storing these, this problem wouldn't exist.. :)  Here is your original question, -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46142827/add-object-to-an-array-in-a-json-file-in-node-js-for-each-request

Comment: @skirtle yes that is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, one idea.

If you alter your appendFile to also add a newline.. after each append, not only would this make it easier to read if you opened it, it would also make easier to parse.

eg.. `fs.appendFile('coords.json', imageCoordinates + '\r\n', finished);`

Because we can't run node here in the browser, in the code below pretend lines is the data read from your file after the above mods with newlines.

I basically generate some valid JSON from splitting and rejoining with commas, and then wrap inside an array.

ps. the `filter(String)` is just to filter out the last array element that would be blank due to the none required last comma.

```js
let lines = '{"x":344,"y":158}\r\n{"x":367,"y":152}\r\n{"x":641,"y":129}\r\n';

var data = JSON.parse('[' + (lines.split('\r\n').filter(String)).join(',') + ']');

console.log(data);
```

Comment: I have implemented your solution. It is running fine but the problem is that it is storing the objects in two different arrays and not in a single array. Can you tell me what could be the solution?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean, if you run the snippet above, there is only 1 array with 3 items in it.

Comment: There is a little bit misunderstanding. The size of the array will depend upon the number of times the user clicks on the screen. Everytime user clicks, the coordinates should be stored in the array. So thats why I cannot implement 'let lines'. The json that I have shown above is the result after three clicks.

Comment: The above snippet is an example of how to parse, the `let lines` is just pretending to be your `coords.json` file that you have read.  It could have 1000 lines, it would still work.  It would then be 1 array with 1000 items in it.

Comment: I am sorry, I cannot understand. Can you please add a bit more detailed code i.e can you add the solution in my function so that I have a better understanding.

Comment: I don't exactly understand the purpose of let lines and how to implement it in my case.

Comment: You can't make this valid JSON as your appending the data, JSON is not a format that's designed to be appended too.  The solution I have given you is for when you want to read the data back. eg. when you use `fs.readFile`.  If you want to have the 'coords.json` be valid all the time, your best bet is to read the file, append your data, and write the whole file back again.  If the read/append/write becomes too resource hungry, another option is to use random file access, but that's a tad bit more complicated.